# Codeiniter and Active Record

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a mysql table like image. I Can't solved (for 3 days I'm losted). Help me please.
Note: Codeigniter with Active records.

I can't post image here! But here is a dropbox's link for it.[Link to image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ro5bpckuffp6p8d/imag2.png)

Thank you. 
Sorry for my English...

Oliveira

Comment: Please post text instead of screenshots. It's a nuisance to have to switch between the image and this question to answer it, plus you can't copy-paste content from images for use in the answer. Secondly, questions without code of any sort are very hard to answer. You should include something to give a bit of context on your problem: "What have you tried?"

Comment: Some half-ass attempt,at least somebody will use the fiddle to finish it through.http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23f58/44

Comment: you dont need perfect english and this is a great question so just describe what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller

`$names = array of distinct name`

then loop `$names array` like this:

```
<?php foreach($names as $nm)
{
    $class[$nm['name']] = select all rows which have name = $nm['name'] 
}?>
```

then pass these two array to the view.
there

```
foreach($names as $nm)
{
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $nm['name']?></td>

    <?php foreach($class[$nm['name']] as $cls)
    {?>
        <td><?php echo $cls['class']?></td>
    <?php }?>
    </tr>
}
```

it work only if each name have exact number of rows. If else try to change this